# Delete specific value from Array in Object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I want to delete one value of an array in an object. I tried two methods, but cannot find a solution. Object function "delete" does not work and array function "splice" doesn't work. What works?

```
  let my_object =  

{
   "contacts_id":[
      1,
      2,
      3
   ],
   "orders_id":[
      2,
      3
   ]
}
```

I want to delete "contacts_id":2, so the result should look like this:

```
{
   "contacts_id":[
      1,
      3
   ],
   "orders_id":[
      2,
      3
   ]
}
```

I'm trying to achieve this by:

```
let my_object_modified = delete my_object[contacts_id][1];
```

This line of code does not delete the value, but sets it to "empty". The result is:

```
{
       "contacts_id":[
          1,
          null,
          3
       ],
       "orders_id":[
          2,
          3
       ]
    }
```

The second way I'm trying to delete the value is by the array function .splice:

```
let my_object_modified = my_object[contacts_id][1].splice(0,1);
```

With this code I get an error "splice is not a function"

Comment: **splice is not a function** means that you are calling splice on something that is not an array. In your case you are trying to splice a number, or single item, in the `contacts_id` array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using Array.prototype.splice ([splice](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/45509/243587))

For example:

```
//print the array
console.log(my_object.contacts_id);

//delete the "contacts_id":2
my_object.contacts_id.splice(1, 1);

//print the new array
console.log(my_object.contacts_id);
```

Answer (score 1):

use filter for this

```js
let my_object =  

{
   "contacts_id":[
      1,
      2,
      3
   ],
   "orders_id":[
      2,
      3
   ]
}

my_object.contacts_id = my_object.contacts_id.filter(x => x!==2)

console.log(my_object)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the array method splice() to remove the desired element.

For example:

Delete a known element:

```
let my_object = {
   "contacts_id":[
      1,
      2,
      3
   ],
   "orders_id":[
      2,
      3
   ]
};

let index = my_object["contacts_id"].indexOf(2);

if (index > -1) {
  my_object["contacts_id"].splice(index, 1);
}

console.log(my_object);
```

Delete any element at index 1:

```
let my_object = {
   "contacts_id":[
      1,
      2,
      3
   ],
   "orders_id":[
      2,
      3
   ]
};

my_object["contacts_id"].splice(1, 1);

console.log(my_object);
```